# Windows Phone 7 Selection_Changed automatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selectionchanged

currently I'm developing an app for WP7 but came across a little problem with a Listbox event call Selection_Change. The problem is that when i return to the page that contains the listbox the selection_change event triggers without being changed at all or without any user input. The listbox code is similar to this:

```
private void lsbHistory_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = lsbHistory.SelectedIndex;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NextPage, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

On the page I navigate to, the only way out of the navigated page is by pressing back button or start button meaning that it will return to the page that contains the listbox. When I Navigate back the selection change triggers leading me sometimes to a exception. Has anyone been through this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider always checking if it's `-1` (the default value).

```
private void lsbHistory_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = lsbHistory.SelectedIndex;
    if (index != -1)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NextPage, UriKind.Relative));
        lsbHistory.SelectedIndex = -1; // Set it to -1, to enable re-selection.   
    }
}
```

Also, you should consider wrapping the `Navigate` call in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to have a better, more smooth, page transition.

Comment: Thank Claus for the response the thing is that when it gets auto selected the index is set to 0 :(. Never thought of using the dispatcher to navigate thanx for that :D

Comment: Then read what @mikael-koskinen wrote. You're clearly selecting it with your own code.

Comment: Hey Claus was developing another app, and encountered the same problem it turns out that when i navigate to another page clicking the listbox item and the pressing back, and the assigning a new itemssource to the list it returns to the selection_changed of the listbox and if you don't validate if(index > -1) it will throw a nullreferrence exception. Thank you Claus :D

Answer (score 1):

The event will be fired when the list is populated.

The simplest solution for you will probably be to add a check that there is nothing selected before triggering your navigation:

```
if (lsbHistory.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    // do navigation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to notice is that when you navigate **back to the page** which containt the ListBox, the ListBox **still has the SelectedItem set** to the value it had when the user navigated away. This means that lsbHistory.SelectedIndex will get the index of the item which was selected when the user navigated forward.

Maybe there's something in your code which presumes that the ListBox's SelectedItem is null when the user navigates to the page?

Comment: I don't recall but I'll look into it again thanx